# Attach rigid body in google cardboard unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have this problem in my game development project that whenever I looked down or drag my mouse down the first person controller doesn't look down.

What I did before the problem occurred:
In the hierarchy I have the google cardboard prefab(with a split frame) and the first person controller with a rigid body so to make my google cardboard prefab walk I deleted the camera of my first person controller then put the camera of my google card board and make it as a child of my first person controller then I change the script from (Head Bob Script) to (Cardboard Head Script). Then the problem occurred it doesn't look down whenever I drag my mouse down.

Comment: Oop's i figured it out already .

Comment: If you think your solution to your problem would help others, please edit your question so it's clearer what the problem actually was, then post your solution as an answer. Otherwise the question is liable to be deleted as unclear.